# C++ Memory Leak Dynamically allocated 2D array and Linked List

Tags: c++

I've been struggling with a memory leak for a few hours, and I'm not sure what the problem is.

My error is this:

```
==3914== 96 (48 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==3914==    at 0x4C2E17F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3914==    by 0x401F0E: DailyTodoList::insert(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) (todolist.cpp:86)
```

I allocate using: 
`Item* newItem = new Item(val, NULL, NULL);
if (newItem == NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();`

which is added into an array, in which each index holds a head to a linked list.
Below is an example:

```
if(numItemsOnDay(dayIndex) == 0)
{
    data_[dayIndex] = newItem;
}
//new head and items already exist in the list
else if(loc == 0 && loc < numItemsOnDay(dayIndex))
{
    Item* tmp = data_[dayIndex];
    data_[dayIndex] = newItem;
    newItem->nextItem = tmp;
}
```

I get rid of everything using the destructor:

```
DailyTodoList::~DailyTodoList()
{
    Item* temp;
    Item* another;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cap_; i++)
    {
        temp = data_[i];
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            while (temp->nextItem != NULL)
            {
                another = temp->nextItem;
                delete temp;
                temp = another;
            }
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    delete[] data_;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You're beholden to doing manual memory management and rolling your own linked list, right? Just making sure that this is a school assignment.

Comment: Yeah, it is my own linked list and i'm not using any templates.

Comment: What John is trying to find out is "Do you have to use your own Linked List?"  This is important because there are a couple linked list classes (or at least they are specified such that they're hard to implement as anything but linked lists) you can use from the C++ Standard library. `std::list`, for example.

Comment: We will need to see more, that [mcve] thing asked for above, to be able to properly answer this question. You'll find that it's quite easy to make sure a resource is released correctly in the destructor, and yet write the program such that there are opportunities to miss calling the destructor.

Comment: Side note: `while (temp->nextItem != NULL)` winds up being clunky. You're generally better off with a `while (temp != NULL)` and a slightly different loop body. You won't need the `if (temp != NULL)`, for one thing.

Comment: The part of the [mre] I'd be most interested in is the code surrounding the provided `if-else-if` statement. Especially since we do not see the `else` clause for the second `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the little code that you have provided, it looks like you are doing something like this:

```
Item* newItem = new Item(val, NULL, NULL);

if (some_test())
    put_newItem_somewhere();

else if (some_other_test())
    put_newItem_somewhere_else();
```

But what if both tests fails? In your case that would be if `numItemsOnDay(dayIndex) != 0` and `loc >= numItemsOnDay(dayIndex)`. Where will the address of the new item be stored? If you don't store it anywhere you will have a memory leak.

(And by the way, counting the number of elements in a list to see if it is empty, is bad practice)